# Flutter: Date picker switch to input mode?

Tags: flutter

Switch to input mode is visible on dartpad but not on actual device or emulator.

https://dartpad.dev/e5a99a851ae747e517b75ac221b73529

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because Dartpad is on channel dev or beta and its not on Stable.